# Rails::MailersController#preview wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through the rails tutorial, and am on chapter 10 setting up mailers. Right now I am on the account_activation email. To ensure I am setting it up the correct way, I have even double checked my code based on the [sample repo](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition), and I am setting it up just like he has.

The full error is: `ArgumentError in Rails::MailersController#preview wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` and is pointing to the code in my `user_mailer#account_activation` method

```
 def account_activation(user) #here 
   @user = user
   mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
 end
```

the test code this is checking against is this

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  # Preview this email at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation
  def account_activation
    user = User.first
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user) #setting up the method call here
  end
end
```

I am not sure why this is happening, because I pass the correct number of arguments via `UserMailer.account_activation(user)`. My only guess is maybe it could be looking at the `UserMailerPreview#account_activation` (which takes no argument) method and is trying to mirror the method at `UserMailer#account_activation` which does take an argument.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you're calling class method and not instance method then it should be

```
 def self.account_activation(user)
   @user = user
   mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
 end
```

and then

```
UserMailer.account_activation(user)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I switched and made them class methods, and that still did not work :(